# Transpose rows to columns keeping some rows as reference in shell

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file that I need to transpose, it looks like this:

```
Person ID| commute to work in hours?| Happiness score?| work satisfaction score?
1234| 2 | 8 | 7
5678| 1 | 7 | 6
6789| 0.5 | 9 | 6
```

I need to pivot this as below:

```
Person ID | Question | Answer
1234 | commute to work in hours? | 2
1234 | Happiness score? | 8
1234 | work satisfaction score? | 7
5678 | commute to work in hours? | 1
5678 | Happiness score? | 7
5678 | work satisfaction score? | 6
6789 | commute to work in hours? | 0.5
6789 | Happiness score? | 9
6789 | work satisfaction score? | 6
```

I have tried using `awk`, and am able to get :

```
1234 | 3
1234 | 8
1234 | 7
5678 | 1
5678 | 7
5678 | 6
6789 | 0.5
6789 | 9
6789 | 6
```

But I am unable to add the question.

```
awk '{
   for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
       unique[$1]=(unique[$1]FS$i); next } END { 
  for (i in unique) { 
       n=split(unique[i],temp); 
       for(j=1;j<=n;j++) 
           print i,temp[j] } }' file
```

Comment: add a pattern as the first bit of code in your `awk` like `NR==1{split($0,hdr_arr);next}` then reference `hdr_arr[1]. hdr_arr[2] ...` to get the correct text from that header line. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

IF you only have three field, you do not need to use loop, so this should work.

```
awk -F\| 'NR==1 {a=$2;b=$3;c=$4;print $1," Question | Answer";next} {print $1,a,$2"\n"$1,b,$3"\n"$1,c,$4}' OFS=" |" file
Person ID | Question | Answer
1234 | commute to work in hours? | 2
1234 | Happiness score? | 8
1234 | work satisfaction score? | 7
5678 | commute to work in hours? | 1
5678 | Happiness score? | 7
5678 | work satisfaction score? | 6
6789 | commute to work in hours? | 0.5
6789 | Happiness score? | 9
6789 | work satisfaction score? | 6
```

Comment: Indeed this is the best option to go for if OP has only 3 fields ;-) +1!

Answer (score 1):

Input:

```
$ cat file_transpose 
Person ID| commute to work in hours?| Happiness score?| work satisfaction score?
1234| 2 | 8 | 7
5678| 1 | 7 | 6
6789| 0.5 | 9 | 6
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS=" |"}NR==1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){buff[i]=$i};print "Person ID | Question | Answer";next}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,buff[i],$i}}' file_transpose 
Person ID | Question | Answer
1234 | commute to work in hours? | 2 
1234 | Happiness score? | 8 
1234 | work satisfaction score? | 7
5678 | commute to work in hours? | 1 
5678 | Happiness score? | 7 
5678 | work satisfaction score? | 6
6789 | commute to work in hours? | 0.5 
6789 | Happiness score? | 9 
6789 | work satisfaction score? | 6
```

**Explanations:**

```
#field separator and output field separator
BEGIN {
       FS = "|"
       #you might want to remove the space
       OFS = " |"
}

# Rule(s)
# On the first line, save all the questions in buff, print the header, jump to next line
NR == 1 { 
       for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
            buff[i] = $i
       }
       print "Person ID | Question | Answer"
       next
 }
 #for the rest of the file, print the first field, each question and associated answer
 {
       for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
           print $1, buff[i], $i
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=" *[|] *"; OFS=" | " }

NR==1 {
    split($0,qs)
    print $1, "Question", "Answer"
    next
}

{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        print $1, qs[i], $i
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Person ID | Question | Answer
1234 | commute to work in hours? | 2
1234 | Happiness score? | 8
1234 | work satisfaction score? | 7
5678 | commute to work in hours? | 1
5678 | Happiness score? | 7
5678 | work satisfaction score? | 6
6789 | commute to work in hours? | 0.5
6789 | Happiness score? | 9
6789 | work satisfaction score? | 6
```